# Xtend/Xtext Datatypes

Tags: code-generation, xtext, xtend

I have a problem with my in Xtext created Datatypes. The problems lies within this function:

```
    «FOR e: bla.EAllAttributes»
      «e.EType.name» «e.name»;
    «ENDFOR»
```

This for-loop just returns EInt or EString for e.EType.name. But i need the terminal rules/datatypes created in my DSL like double, boolean and so on. It seems every terminal rule with a string expression is returned as EString and rules with only numbers are returned as EInt. Enumerations are correctly returned though...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the manual there is a section explaining your issue. See "Reference Documentation", "The Grammar Language", "The Syntax", "Rules", "Terminal Rules", "Return Types":

> Each terminal rule returns an atomic value (an Ecore EDataType). By default, it's assumed that an instance of ecore::EString) should be returned. However, if you want to provide a different type you can specify it.

That section also outlines the grammar changes and registration of the value converters you must provide.

There is also another sections "Data Type Rules" which basically says that it is the same as in the "terminal rule" case and forwards you to the "Value converter" section.